# cordova app to wp8 window.location not working windows phone

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have created an app with jquery mobile and html5. I created a wp8 package using cordova for the same and have openend the solution with visual studio. The issue I am facing is that the window.location is not working. I have given
`window.location.href='home.html#basic'` making it redirect to a particular div. I also tried window.location.replace. Using show and hide dive makes the functionality work but many css issues are coming when i use div show and hide. I have gone through many previous questions but still not found any solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all it worked i changed it to  $.mobile.changePage('#basic'); and it worked